# Merge ews and exchangewebservices tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

The [ews](/questions/tagged/ews) and [exchangewebservices](/questions/tagged/exchangewebservices) tags have the same meaning, as identified by the tag wikis, and so ought to be merged. (I've no reputation in either so I can't directly propose a merger.)

Comment: exchangews appears to also be the same meaning (it was suggested as a retag of ews)

Comment: Just giving this a bump as both tags still exist

Comment: +1, also add exchange-web-services to the list